# Android project for social networking system

Tags: android

Hi everyone i have one question about android.

I have created a social networking website. Now i want to make my own website to android application. I am a good designer for android application template like (material design ext.).

I searched on the internet how to created login and register script from android aplication using PHP,MYSQL and i found some example but that examples is not clearly.

My question is how can i use my PHP code in android aplication ?

Note: I am a new on android only php section. My website link is [oobenn](http://www.oobenn.com)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't try to port the website on Android. You should instead:

1. create REST APIs for your website exposing JSON Data.
2. download Android Studio
3. start developing an Android native application connecting to your website, retrieving data (JSON) and showing data to the user through the native Android UI elements

I strongly recommend you this course https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853

Comment: i created my android application template. I want to integrate my php code in my application template. You said i need to use JSON Data right ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to develop webservice in PHP and call that webservice functions in Android application.